# NewLine in centered DataGridTextColumn Header with Resources File

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I would like to achieve that the Header in a DataGridColumn has a newline (2 lines) and each text is centered. Furthermore the text should come from a resource file.
I've tried to make a newline in the resource file with ALT+ENTER but the Text is not centered and looks like this:

```
| LINE1LONG |
| LINE2     |
```

My DataGridTextColumn in WPF

```
 <DataGridTextColumn Width="4*" IsReadOnly="False" 
  Header="{x:Static p:Resources.DG_HEADER_DESC}" Binding="{Binding Description, Mode=TwoWay}">
  </DataGridTextColumn>
```

The centering works for a single line but not with two lines with the following style:

```
 <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
        </Style>
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 4):

you can create a custom template for the header where you center the text within a textblock and not the textblock within the header:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                <GridViewColumnHeader>
                            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="this is a text&#x0a;and here some more" />
                </GridViewColumnHeader>
            </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain the ability to use a resource file

```
    <DataGrid>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn>

                <!-- Column Width--!>
                    <DataGridTextColumn.Width>4</DataGridTextColumn.Width> 
                <!-- Column Width--!>

                <DataGridTextColumn.IsReadOnly>False</DataGridTextColumn.IsReadOnly>

                <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                   <Binding Path="{Binding Description, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>

                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <DataGridColumnHeader Content="{x:Static p:Resources.DG_HEADER_DESC}" 
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                          HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
                                          TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center"> 

                        <!-- Header Width--!>
                            <DataGridColumnHeader.Width>4</DataGridColumnHeader.Width>
                       <!-- Header Width--!>

                    </DataGridColumnHeader> 
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```